# SWT UI hangs even when a new thread is started

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I'm starting a new thread using `Display.getDefault().asyncExec()`. The thread does something like this:

```
public void run()
{
    while (! condition)
    {
      //do some processing
      mainWindow.updateStatus(..); //this will call a setText method on a label in 
                    //the original thread
    }
}
```

However when I run this thread, the program hangs rather than showing the status smoothly in the label. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Display.asyncExec()` does not start a new thread. See [Display.getCurrent().asyncExec not run in parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994720/display-getcurrent-asyncexec-not-run-in-parallel).

Comment: @MarttiKäärik Then how can I run a new thread which will also update SWT UI?

Comment: @MarttiKäärik If I try to access the UI from another thread, that would give some thread access errors, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstand the concept of thread. What you call thread is actually just a piece of code that you schedule to be executed on the (UI) thread.

As a rule, code on UI thread should execute quickly and return as soon as possible. Your while loop most likely violates this rule. The solution is to take the loop out of the UI thread i.e. the run method and put it around the `Display.asyncExec()` call.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on Käärik's answer: your code should look like

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    public void run()
    {
        while (! condition)
        {
            //do some processing without touching the screen
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mainWindow.updateStatus(..);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and then you run it as `new Thread(new MyTask())` or e.g. schedule it on a thread pool to repeat each 10 seconds.